# Read all possible HEX 16 bytes sequences in a file and print each one of them

Tags: c++, printing, hex, byte

I'm trying to read all HEX binary bytes of the file (the hex values you can see opening whatever it in a hex viewer) file of whatever size and then generate and print all those as hex binary bytes as well on a new file with all the possible 16 bytes sequences from it.
Possibly with c++, here's an example of what I want accomplish:

From a file like this

```
00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F
10 11 12 13
```

The new file will be this

```
00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F 10
02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F 10 11
03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F 10 11 12
04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F 10 11 12 13
```

EDIT: I'm considering the file's hex values (the ones you can see with any type of hex viewer

Comment: Suggestion: Read up on the permutation functions in the [`<algorithm>` library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) and then make an attempt at solving this problem yourself. We'll be able to help you much better if you ask questions about an attempt. You might not even have to ask questions. Everybody wins!

Comment: Yes it's possible. Stack Overflow is not a "write my code for me" site

Comment: What part of the assignment are you having issues with?  Hint:  see `std::hex`.

Comment: Ok, so I was having trouble at the start of this, my idea is to load all the file bytes in a big array, and move a 16 bytes range on it (all this in while !EOF)
This will work i guess but is the right and best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Just create a left/right rotation function that loads up all bytes then rotate by 2 instead of 1 byte. Right rotation in python is: return s[strlen(str)-n:strlen(str)] + s[0:strlen(str)-n], you can see here some base implementation in C. https://gist.github.com/heatblazer/4004983472a2cf0a0fc42ad0cf912c80

Comment: the file is quite big around 7400 kb

Answer (score 0):

The task is not very complicated.

At first, we open the input file and the output file. For both, we check, if they could be opened. For this we use the `std::fstream` constructor. See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/basic_ifstream). And, we use the `if` statement with initializer. Please see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if).

So, now both files are open. After they leave their scope (After the end of the `if` statement, the closing `}`), the files will be closed automatically by the destructor of the [std::fstream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream).

Good, understood. Next, we want to read the data from the input text file. The textfile, as shown above, consists of 2 byte sized sub-strings, corresponding to a hex value in text format. The substrings are separated by a space.

To read that, we can use formatted input functions, like in

```
inputFileStream >> substring0 >> substring1 >> substring2 >> substring3 . . . .
```

But since we do not know, how many bytes will come, we can use an `std::istream_iterator`. With that iterator, we can iterate over all elements in the source file. And, an element will be a substring, as explained above.

You may imagine, that the `>>` operator will be repeatedly called.

Next we want to store all those sub-strings. For this we use a `std::vector`. This can grow dynamically in size. We will use the so called range-constructor of the `std::vector`. See [here, constructor number 5](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector). This expects a begin and an end iterator of some source range and will then copy the data from there to the `std::vector`.

The begin iterator is the `std::istream_iterator` as shown above. The end iterator will be its default constructed pendant: `{}`. Please see [here, constructor number 1](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator/istream_iterator).

Please note that we do not need to define the type of the `std::vector`. It will be deduced automatically using CTAD. Please see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction).

Then, we want to output 16 byte blocks of the data stored in the `std::vector`. For this, we use a loop, where we increase an index `i` in every loop run.

Additionally, we use `std::copy_n` from the C++ algorithm library. Please see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n).

We always copy 16 substrings (or less, if not enough available) to the output file stream. For that, we use the `std::ostream_iterator`, which will work similar to the input iterator. Please see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator).

And that's basically it.

Please see one of many possible solutions below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

std::string inputFileName{ "input.txt" };
std::string outputFileName{ "output.txt" };

int main() {

    // Open the input file and check, if it could be opened
    if (std::ifstream inputFileStream{ inputFileName }; inputFileStream) {

        // Open the output file and check, if it could be opened
        if (std::ofstream outputFileStream{ outputFileName }; outputFileStream) {

            // Read the complete input file. Use range constructor of vector to read all hex sub-strings
            std::vector data(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(inputFileStream), {});

            int i{};
            // Copy 16 bytes from input data to output file, starting with increasing index
            do {
                std::copy_n(data.begin() + i, (data.size() < 16)? data.size() : 16, std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(outputFileStream, " "));
                outputFileStream << '\n';
                
            } while ( i++ < (static_cast<int>(data.size()) - 16));
        }
        else {
            std::cerr << "\n*** Error: Could not open output file '" << outputFileName << "'\n";
        }
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "\n*** Error: Could not open input file '" << inputFileName << "'\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It has been compiled and tested with C++17. In MS Visual Studio 19 Community Edition. Add the related compiler option

Comment: I see, I was using DEV c++, I also had visual studio so I will try doing it myself there and compare it to yours

Comment: I tried it on visual studio 19 community using c++17, i still get a bunch of errors like expected ")" at | if (std::ifstream inputFileStream{ inputFileName }; inputFileStream) { |
and | argument list for class template "std::vector" is missing |

Comment: No, You are not using C++17. The error messages show that. Goto Project --> Properties --> C/C++ --> Language --> C++ Language Standard --> Preview - Features from the lates C++ . . .  for the active configuration

Comment: Ok this program works with the example "bytes" written as text strings, however I am trying to get it working with the file Hex values, I want read the file hex bytes and generate a new file that will look like the example in a hex editor view.

Comment: Hm, my program does exactly what is specified in the question. It takes a "file like this" and produces the output. Exactly as specified. I have the feeling now, that you want to read a binary file and show it as hex dump. Can you please click the edit button under your question, and state exactly that. Please make a maximum precise requirements list. I now also have doubts about the required output file. Please explain in detail. Thank you

Comment: Yes I do not talk about a reading the "strings" of a file but his binary HEX values, and the print will generate those values in the same way ofc.
Imagine the example I made with considering those hex bytes as the ones you see on the left on HxD when u open a file (where you also see the offsets)
I thought the example represented with HEX values an using the word BYTE were enough to made it clear what I was trying to accomplish